# need help to fix Error 201 in Pascal

Tags: c++, pascal

I'm trying to convert this C++ code to Pascal but I'm getting error 201. Can somebody help me fix it?

**C++ code**:

```
int n; 
bool a[100];

void show()
{
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        if (a[i]) 
            printf("%d ", i);
    printf("\n"); 
}

void bt(int u)
{
    if (u==n+1) 
    {
        show();
        return ;
    }
    a[u]=0;
    bt(u+1);
    a[u]=1;
    bt(u+1); 
}

main()
{
    scanf("%d", &n);
    bt(1); 
}
```

**Pascal code**:

```
type data = integer; var i,n:integer; a:array[0..100] of integer; b:array[0..100] of integer;

procedure show; var i:data; begin
    for i:=1 to n do
    begin
    if (b[i]=0) then
    writeln(a[i]);
    end; end;

procedure bt(i:data); var u:data; begin

    if (u=n+1) then
     begin
         show();
     end
    else
      b[u]:=0;
      bt(u+1);
      b[u]:=1;
      bt(u+1);

end;

begin
    write('Nhap n ');
    readln(n);
    bt(1); end.
```

Thanks, and sorry for my level english

Comment: FWIW, that looks much more like C than like C++.

Answer (score 1):

My c++ is a little rusty, but that doesn't look like an accurate translation to me.  Try something like this instead:

```
type
  data = integer;

var
  // i, 
  n : integer;
  a : array[0..100] of boolean; // integer;
//  b : array[0..100] of integer;

procedure SetUp;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 100 do
    a[i] := True;
end;

procedure show;
var
  i : data;
begin
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    if a[i] then
      write(i);
  end;
  writeln;
end;

procedure bt(i : data);
var
  u : data;
begin
  if ( u = n + 1) then
   begin
     show();
   end;
///  else
//    b[u] := False;
  bt(u + 1);
  a[u] := True;
  bt(u+1);
end;

begin
  SetUp;
  write('Nhap n ');
  readln(n);
  bt(1);
  readln;
end.
```

Pascal has a native Boolean type, hence my changed declaration of array a.  I have included a routine SetUp to explicitly initialize it.  I'm not sure where your array b comes from.

Btw, if SetUp sets the values of a's elements to false, all the output you will get is a series of blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

An as exact as possible conversion would be:

```
program StackOverflow1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  n: Integer;
  a: array[0..99] of Boolean;

procedure show;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to n do       // This is very suspicious! 
    if a[i] then
      Write(i, ' ');
  Writeln;
end;

procedure bt(u: Integer);
begin
  if u = n + 1 then
  begin
    Show;
    Exit;
  end;
  a[u] := False;
  bt(u + 1);
  a[u] := True;
  bt(u + 1);
end;

begin
  Writeln('enter n:');
  Readln(n);
  bt(1);
end.
```

The line

```
for i := 1 to n do     // for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
```

looks as if it should have been

```
for i := 0 to n - 1 do // for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
```

C does not have range checks, so there it does not give you an error. But your Pascal has, and that loop is probably why you get runtime error 201.

I don't know what this program is supposed to do, but it would not surprise me if the C program did not deliver the correct result.

It would also not surprise me if, for values of `n` close to 99, you would get a stack overflow error (or its equivalent runtime number). If the user enters a values for `n > 99`, this will probably cause a range check error, sometime, if the stack overflow error doesn't come first.

I tried with `n = 80`, and it took ages, so I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>'ed it.

---

Alternatively, you could use

```
  a: array[1..100] of Boolean;
```

but that does not match the C program. In C, all arrays are zero-based. If the original C program works correctly, then my Pascal translation should as well.

Answer (score 0):

Error 201 appears to be a range check error (http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap4.html).

In procedure `bt`, you are comparing `u` with `n+1` even though you have not initialized `u`. This can cause weird results as it could be any valid integer. Unlike certain other languages but similarly to C, Pascal does not initialize variables to a default (http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse23.html).

Comment: "Pascal does not initialize variables to a default "  Not generally true in Delphi.  Globals are, but locals are not unless they are managed types like *string*.

Comment: I see `void bt(int u)`, so u is probably initialized.

Comment: `u` is the parameter passed to the function `bt` so it is initialized (in `main` it is called as `bt(1)`), while `n` should be initialized by `scanf`... perhaps, OP's code doesn't check.

Comment: The questioner didn't say they were using Delphi.